# How to bind a linux GUI button to a command?

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface

I have 2 basic questions in Linux GUI design(e.g: QT):

1. How to bind a GUI button with a linux command/script?
2. How to save a set of GUI input parameters from user into a file on hard disk?
3. With 1 and 2 above, the aim is to let user specify a set of parameters on the GUI, and then when user click the "Run" button, the linux command will be run with the supplied parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Some tools for building simple GUIs to run commands include:

- [Zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity)
- [Yad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/)
- [XDialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/)

If TUI (text) is an option, look at:

- [Whiptail](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)
- [Dialog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807)

Each of these has an extensive `--help(-*)` menu(s) to describe the different widgets they provide. E.g., Zenity’s file selection dialog is described with: `zenity --help-file-selection`

Comment: Thanks Micah, very helpful! I will have a look at them.